laravel Eloquent ::has() QueryException on different connection
I have two databases,
db1 :

users table

db2 :

infos table

Each table I created has a Models, and I set a different connection for each one:
User.php => protected $connection = "db1";
Info.php => protected $connection = "db2";
In Model User.php there is a relationship with the Info.php Model.
    public function info(): HasOne
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Info::class);
    }

The problem is when:
$users = User::has('info')->get();

"SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'db1.infos' doesn't exist (Connection: db1, SQL: select * from `users` where exists (select * from `infos` where `users`.`id` = `infos`.`user_id`))"

I did ->dd() and it results in an incorrect query
select * from `users` where exists (select * from `infos` where `users`.`id` = `infos`.`user_id`)

The query should be like this:
select * from `users` where exists (select * from `db2`.`infos` where `users`.`id` = `db2`.`infos`.`user_id`)


You need to set a connection in the relationship, so we have multiple ways to do it:

Using Eloquent

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    protected $connection = "db1";

    public function info()
    {
        $info = new Info;
        $info->setConnection('db2');
        return $this->hasOne(Info::class, 'user_id')->setModel($info);
    }

    public static function usersWithInfo()
    {
        return static::query()
            ->whereExists(function ($query) {
                $query->select(DB::raw(1))
                    ->from('db2.infos')
                    ->whereRaw('db2.infos.user_id = users.id');
            })
            ->get();
    }
}


Manually Query with Joins

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

$users = DB::table('users')
    ->join('db2.infos', 'users.id', '=', 'db2.infos.user_id')
    ->select('users.*')
    ->get();

